# Grails rendering plugin does not work in Grails3.2.4?

Tags: pdf, grails, plugins, rendering

I want to render a view to pdf and tried using the Grails rendering plugin 2.0.3

I tried the simplest gsp-file to start with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!--
  To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
  To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
  and open the template in the editor.
-->

<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Sample title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Sample line</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in the controller:

```
    def report() {
        def OfferHeader oh = OfferHeader.get(15)
        println(">>> Offerheader: "+oh.sawMill)
//        render(template: "/offerHeader/Test")
        renderPdf(template: "/offerHeader/Test",  filename: "offertrapport.pdf")

    }
```

And that ends with:

```
2017-04-14 11:26:55.989 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.g.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver   : NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /offerHeader/report/15
Stacktrace follows:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:210)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:187)
    at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.groovy:64)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:62)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1337)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1197)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:426)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:173)
    at grails.plugins.rendering.document.RenderEnvironment.init(RenderEnvironment.groovy:31)
    at grails.plugins.rendering.document.RenderEnvironment.with(RenderEnvironment.groovy:68)
    at grails.plugins.rendering.document.RenderEnvironment.with(RenderEnvironment.groovy:60)
    at grails.plugins.rendering.document.XhtmlDocumentService.generateXhtml(XhtmlDocumentService.groovy:65)
    at grails.plugins.rendering.document.XhtmlDocumentService.createDocument(XhtmlDocumentService.groovy:35)
    at grails.plugins.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:36)
    at grails.plugins.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:35)
    at grails.plugins.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:65)
    at grails.plugins.rendering.RenderingTrait$Trait$Helper.render(RenderingTrait.groovy:66)
    at grails.plugins.rendering.RenderingTrait$Trait$Helper.renderPdf(RenderingTrait.groovy:45)
    at com.torntrading.portal.OfferHeaderController.$tt__report(OfferHeaderController.groovy:123)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

What am I missing? Or is it not expected to work with this version of grails (3.2.4)?

Maybe there is better plugins to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First add the following dependency to build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    runtime "org.springframework:spring-test:4.2.1.RELEASE"
}
```

Then lets say we're going to render the pdf on the click of a link so in gsp:

```
<g:link action="report" params='[offerId: "${offer.id}"]'>To PDF</g:link>
```

Then in controller:

```
def report() {
    def offer = Offer.get( params.offerId )
    renderPdf(template: "offerpdf", model: [offer: offer],  filename: "offer.pdf")
}
```

In your offer views directory you'd have a template gsp named `_offerpdf.gsp`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Offer</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Offer: ${offer.id}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! That made it, I mean the line in build.gradle was what I missed. I just wonder how you found this thing? I've been googling a lot finding a solution and read the documentation etc. but with no result. It could be helpful to know where to look for such things.

Comment: I burned a few hours on this too. :(   There is an issue opened back in June 2014 that describes how the grails plugin is missing the runtime dependency.  https://github.com/gpc/rendering/issues/17.  I think most people accidentally avoid this error because other plugins do have this runtime dependency defined.  (like the mail plugin).

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, you need to add a dependency in **build.gradle** to make it work:

```
runtime "org.springframework:spring-test:4.2.1.RELEASE"
```

Comment: Oh, how did you find it? Maybe you read accepted answer??

Comment: I think so, but I am not sure why that dependency it’s needed for this issue