# Grails rendering plugin with grails 3.1.1

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

i am trying to convert from gsp to pdf with [this plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/rendering)

and [i also read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156614/grails-generating-pdf-from-gsp)

but i still get some error like this

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1337) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1197) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:426) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:173) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at grails.plugins.rendering.document.RenderEnvironment.init(RenderEnvironment.groovy:31) ~[rendering-2.0.3.jar:na]
    at grails.plugins.rendering.document.RenderEnvironment.with(RenderEnvironment.groovy:68) ~[rendering-2.0.3.jar:na]
    at grails.plugins.rendering.document.RenderEnvironment.with(RenderEnvironment.groovy:60) ~[rendering-2.0.3.jar:na]
    at grails.plugins.rendering.document.XhtmlDocumentService.generateXhtml(XhtmlDocumentService.groovy:65) ~[rendering-2.0.3.jar:na]
    at grails.plugins.rendering.document.XhtmlDocumentService.createDocument(XhtmlDocumentService.groovy:35) ~[rendering-2.0.3.jar:na]
```

this is my code.

```
 def createPdfReport = {
    def cif = corporateUserService.getCurrentCifUser().cif
    def perintahkerjaIns = PerintahKerja.findByCifAndId(cif,params.id)
    def perintahkerjaDets = PerintahKerjaDetail.findAllByPerintahKerja(perintahkerjaIns,[sort:"pohon",order:"asc"])
    def perintahpekerja = PerintahPekerja.findAllByPerintahKerja(perintahkerjaIns)

    renderPdf(template: '/perintahKerja/templatprintperintahkerja',model: [jumlahpohon: perintahkerjaDets.size(), cif: cif, perintahLerjaInstance:perintahkerjaIns, perintahKerjaDetails:perintahkerjaDets, perintahPekerjaList: perintahpekerja], filename: "PerintahKerja")
}
```

i don't know what i missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following dependency to build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    runtime "org.springframework:spring-test:4.2.1.RELEASE"
}
```

I helped another user with a few rendering plugin related questions recently so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408914/grails-rendering-plugin-does-not-work-in-grails3-2-4/43425359#43425359) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43847025/grails-rendering-plugin-fails-when-app-is-deployed/43871020#43871020) may be of use

Comment: hi, your solution was great, but are you know how to set it to "Lanscape"?

Comment: Not sure, maybe play with the css size http://gpc.github.io/rendering/guide/single.html#4.%20Sizing

Comment: i already set css to landscape `size: landscape;` but when export to pdf, still potrait

Comment: Sorry can't help here, probably best to create a new question

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the plugin works with grails 3? Since i read the plugin github, it says that the build is failing and there is an open ticket since 2 years ago regarding the problem that looks very much like what you have, but until now it hasn't been resolved yet.
Last commit at github is also about 2 years ago.
The open ticket is using grails 2, so i think, the plugin won't work for grails 3 (since it problably not updated to grails 3 plugin)